# Defining extension method for fluent use

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, fluent, nbuilder

I am trying to add an extension method that generates a random HashSet of ints for use with NBuilder mocking library.

This is the method I would like to shorten into a simple extension method:

```
using System;
using FizzWare.NBuilder;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FakeData
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public HashSet<int> AssociatedIds { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var people = Builder<Person>.CreateListOfSize(50)
                .All()
                    .With(p => p.AssociatedIds =
                        Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
                            .Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(new Random().Next(1, 1000), x))
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
                            .Take(new Random().Next(1, 50))
                            .Select(x => x.Item2)
                            .ToHashSet())
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace the `With()` so it would instead look like:

```
var people = Builder<Person>.CreateListOfSize(50)
    .All()
        .RandomHashInt(p => p.AssociatedIds, 1, 50)
    .Build();
```

Something like this:

```
public static IOperable<T> RandonHashInt<T>(this IOperable<T> record, Expression<Func<T, HashSet<int>>> property, int min, int max)
{
    //add hashset
    return record;
}
```

Can someone point me in right direction please

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Which part is not clear?  I show working code and then the method where I need to add the code but I need help working out how to reference `property` inside `record`.  I am not sure how I can make it clearer but if you tell me which part is not clear i will try best to re-write it.

Comment: I didn't ask it to be clear. I asked for a [mcve]. Did you read that link? I want to be able to copy, paste, and compile your code.

Comment: I did read it but I mistook your intentions, my apologies.  I thought you were saying it was not clear,.  I added the class and reference to question

Comment: Could you please help me with being able to copy, paste, and compile your code? Right now I can't do that.

Comment: I added namespace, you can copy now without having to change anything but you will have to add the NBuilder and Faker.Net nuget package to compile

Comment: "CS0234 The type or namespace name 'NameFaker' does not exist in the namespace 'Faker' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: For me NBuilder seems to reference it when it is installed but it's actually not relevant to the extension method so I deleted it.  Please take updated code

Comment: Seems that there are multiple faker nuget packages and they expose the methods through different paths and names.  Just adding footnote for the record.

Comment: You need to change `Func<T, HashSet<int>> property` to `Expression<Func<T, HashSet<int>>> property` - then you can use reflection to get the proeprty name and then use `PropertyInfo.SetValue`.

Comment: I can see how to get the property name but cant see how I can use `PropertyInfo.SetValue` on `record`.  Can you give me another hint?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a different solution

Comment: You should not "new up" a random each time. Create a static / member variable one once and reuse it - else the random numbers will contain many identical runs.  You can shorten your creation of randomness to :   `.With(p => p.AssociatedIds = new HashSet<int> (Enumerable.Range(0, 50).OrderBy(e => Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Take(r.Next(1, 50)))` with `static Random r == new Random();`  somewhere in your class.

Comment: Great tip, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked inside source code on NBuilder `With()` method and copied the way it was done there:

```
public static IOperable<T> WithRandonHashInt<T>(this IOperable<T> record, Expression<Func<T, HashSet<int>>> property, int min, int max)
{
    var declaration = record as IDeclaration<T>;

    var rand = new Random();

    declaration.ObjectBuilder.With(property,
                Enumerable.Range(min, max)
                    .OrderBy(e => Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
                    .Take(rand.Next(min, max))
                    .ToHashSet());

    return (IOperable<T>)declaration;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use a `Guid` where you want random numbers. `Guid`s are not guaranteed to be random. They are guaranteed to be unique. There is a difference.

Comment: There is a tiny chance the same Guid can be generated.